# Does one need a transit visa for Athens?

Tags: visas, schengen, transit, athens

A friend of mine is traveling from Iran to Vienna, he has got a Visa for 6 months. We were able to find flights as cheap as $130.15 with Aegean Airlines. ( We have never heard of such an airline before )

Anyways, there is a layover of an hour in Athens. Does he need to get a transit Visa?

Comment: Aegean Airline has been around for about 17 years now.

Comment: Aegean is the biggest Greek Airline. And if he's Iranian, yes, he Needs an airside transit visa. If he's not Iranian, please tell us his nationality